# React Meteor How to execute a function after withTracker data arrives?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am publishing data from server and catching it using withTracker.

```
    export default withTracker(() => {
     let towndatasub = Meteor.subscribe("userTownDataPublisher",Meteor.userId());
  let resourcedatasub = Meteor.subscribe("userResourcePublisher",Meteor.userId());

      return{
    townData : Towns.find({"ownerId":Meteor.userId()}).fetch(),
    resourceData : Resources.find({"ownerId":Meteor.userId()}).fetch()

      }

    })(TownPage);
```

The problem is i would like to run a function when townData and resourceData arrives.If i call updateResources in componentDidMount i get undefined on this.props.componentWillReceive props not called.townData and this.props.resourceData

```
updateResources = () =>{



Meteor.call("updateUserResources",Meteor.userId(),(err,result)=>{
if(err){
  console.log(err)
}else{
  console.log("asdasd");

      //console.log(this.props.resourceData); undefined
      // here i will do something with this.props.resourceData

}

})
      }
```

So where should i call updateResources function to not get undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `componentDidMount` is only called once when a page is loaded, right after the first call to `render` finishes. Therefore, you shouldn't call `updateResources` there since there's a chance that the collections haven't finished loading from the server by then. I would recommend calling it in `render` because `render` will be called once before the data has arrived and again after the data arrives.

Secondly, if you want to be even more accurate with when the data arrives, you can return two more properties in `withTracker` involving the `ready` function like so,

```
export default withTracker(() => {
    let towndatasub = Meteor.subscribe("userTownDataPublisher",Meteor.userId());
    let resourcedatasub = Meteor.subscribe("userResourcePublisher",Meteor.userId());

    return{
        townData : Towns.find({"ownerId":Meteor.userId()}).fetch(),
        resourceData : Resources.find({"ownerId":Meteor.userId()}).fetch(),
        townsReady : towndatasub.ready(),
        resourcesReady : resourcedatasub.ready()
    }

})(TownPage);
```

And then in render, you can call `updateResources` only when the data has arrived,

```
if(this.props.townsReady && this.props.resourcesReady) {
    this.updateResources();
}
```